# What parts of a SELECT cannot be validated without access to underlying data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, validation, parsing

Without having access to a database, validating that a correlated subquery returns a scalar might be impossible to accurately do in a parser as it would need access to the data, for example:

```
SELECT
     name,
     -- statement might return a valid scalar;
     -- or may return multiple rows;
     -- only the underlying data can answer that
     (SELECT relation FROM relatives WHERE relatives.person_id=person.id) first_relative
FROM person
```

Are there any other types of expressions that would be impossible to validate without having access to the underlying data?

For example, the above would probably validate using [`SET PARSEONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but may not actually be valid SQL statement -- it depends on the underlying data.

Comment: FWIW - your example _is_ a valid SQL statement.  It will throw a run-time error during execution if it returns multiple rows, but that doesn't make it an invalid statement.

Comment: So, I don't know, write it in a way that doesn't use a subquery?

Comment: @AaronBertrand these are user-entered statements that I'm seeing if they're possible to validate without access to a database.

Comment: So teach your users better SQL? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand hmm, I suppose in the above case though we could tack on a `LIMIT 1` and hat would fix that particular issue though...

Comment: Not in SQL Server, you'd need TOP 1. You should probably pick which engine you want to support because the exact same solution will be unlikely to solve for both.

Comment: As @squillman points out, if a SQL statement yields an error when executed, but that error can be eliminated by altering the data in a participating table, then the statement can't be said to contain invalid SQL.

Comment: You could join to a query with row_number and include rn = 1 in the join

Comment: You don't need access to the data, only the schema. You only need to verify that `relatives.person_id` and `person.id` have `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints, and then by definition only one row can be returned. In this case that appears not to be the case, so it is incorrect code anyway. Therefore you need a `TOP 1`/`LIMIT 1`. In SQL Server the error message is enforced by an `Assert` in the plan. If this is not present then the compiler deduced that only one row is returned.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I would say that it *is* incorrect code, because it is possible for it to return an error. Always code defensively: anything that could happen may happen. The fact that it compiles doesn't mean it's correct

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for this that's very helpful. So in SQL Server, even if there is one row in the entire table it would raise an error on an Assert because there is no unique key there, even though it would return a valid result-set (and would, for example in MySQL or Postgres) ?

Comment: No it would not raise an error if there is only one row in actual fact, but the existence of the `Assert` means that it *could* do so. If the `Assert` is not there then no error can ever be raised.